# Adding more directories to url using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_write to pull urls out of my database. I have it working at a basic level, but what I am stuck on is creating complex URLs using various slugs pulled from the database as directories in the URL.

Currently the url before using mod_rewrite looks like:

```
www.domainname.co.uk/company?=1&staff=3
```

Which takes you to a staff profile within an appropriately styled company page.

But what I want the URL to look like is:

```
www.domainname.co.uk/COMPANY-NAME/STAFF-NAME
```

My htaccess currently looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^c/(.*)$ ./company.php?company=$1
```

Which results in the URL

```
www.domainname.co.uk/c/COMPANY-NAME
```

How do I add the second level directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use on additional rule for that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ company.php?company=$1&staff=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^c/([\w-]+)/?$ company.php?company=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]+)(/?)$ /company.php?company=$1&staff=$2 [NC,L]


That should allow urls of the type:
www.domainname.co.uk/COMPANY-NAME/STAFF-NAME
```

Comment: If I wanted to add a rule to go to just www.domainname.co.uk/COMPANY-NAME would it be something like RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]+)(/?)$ /company.php?company=$1 [NC,L] ?