# .htaccess RewriteCond for nice URL

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, server

Using Apache / PHP Server, the URLs I have to enter currently look like

```
www.mypage.com/?link=page1
www.mypage.com/?link=external
www.mypage.com/?link=another666
```

Instead I want to be able to just enter

```
www.mypage.com/page1
www.mypage.com/external
www.mypage.com/another666
```

Do I need to use a RewriteCond in .htaccess? If yes, how to set it up? or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: [See if this answer helps you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39100274/548225)

Comment: "Instead I want to be able to just enter" - Presumably you have (or will) changed the URLs in your application to the new URLs?